# Where is ServiceStack.Data.SqlMapper.QueryMultiple and ServiceStack.Data.DynamicParameters

Tags: servicestack

I recently upgraded ServiceStack related libraries (specially ServiceStack 2.9.25), and with previous releases we had ServiceStack.Data namespace and we were using ServiceStack.Data.DynamicParameter class and IDbConnection extension methods such as Execute and QueryMultiple. But in latest version we don't have this namespace so as the above classes and methods. Are these moved to somewhere else and any alternative classes/methods to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlMapper / Dapper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) has now moved to `ServiceStack.Razor.Dapper` namespace which is in the `ServiceStack.Razor` project.

Comment: Thanks Demis, this solved my compile issues, and also I found that in new version ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController.SessionKey is no longer there so what I did was simply add similar property into my base controller as we have used it in our solution,

<pre>
        protected string SessionKey
        {
            get
            {
                var sessionId = SessionFeature.GetSessionId();
                return sessionId == null ? null : SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(sessionId);
            }
        }
</pre>
So I hope this is fine as well, and going to test for any runtime issues.